# Updated GCC to v5.4.0 on Cygwin. cmath generates errors

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

So I just updated my gcc installation on Cygwin from v5.3.0 to v5.4.0. I made sure to update gcc-core as well. Now when I try to compile a very simple code I get the following errors :

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin/bits/stdc++.h:41:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/Mehdi/Documents/ClionProjects/Playground/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1073:11: error: '::acoshl' has not been declared
   using ::acoshl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1077:11: error: '::asinhl' has not been declared
   using ::asinhl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1081:11: error: '::atanhl' has not been declared
   using ::atanhl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1085:11: error: '::cbrtl' has not been declared
   using ::cbrtl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1089:11: error: '::copysignl' has not been declared
   using ::copysignl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1093:11: error: '::erfl' has not been declared
   using ::erfl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1097:11: error: '::erfcl' has not been declared
   using ::erfcl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1101:11: error: '::exp2l' has not been declared
   using ::exp2l;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1105:11: error: '::expm1l' has not been declared
   using ::expm1l;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1109:11: error: '::fdiml' has not been declared
   using ::fdiml;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1113:11: error: '::fmal' has not been declared
   using ::fmal;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1117:11: error: '::fmaxl' has not been declared
   using ::fmaxl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1121:11: error: '::fminl' has not been declared
   using ::fminl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1129:11: error: '::ilogbl' has not been declared
   using ::ilogbl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1133:11: error: '::lgammal' has not been declared
   using ::lgammal;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1137:11: error: '::llrintl' has not been declared
   using ::llrintl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1141:11: error: '::llroundl' has not been declared
   using ::llroundl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1145:11: error: '::log1pl' has not been declared
   using ::log1pl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1149:11: error: '::log2l' has not been declared
   using ::log2l;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1153:11: error: '::logbl' has not been declared
   using ::logbl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1157:11: error: '::lrintl' has not been declared
   using ::lrintl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1161:11: error: '::lroundl' has not been declared
   using ::lroundl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1165:11: error: '::nanl' has not been declared
   using ::nanl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1169:11: error: '::nearbyintl' has not been declared
   using ::nearbyintl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1173:11: error: '::nextafterl' has not been declared
   using ::nextafterl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1175:11: error: '::nexttoward' has not been declared
   using ::nexttoward;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1176:11: error: '::nexttowardf' has not been declared
   using ::nexttowardf;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1177:11: error: '::nexttowardl' has not been declared
   using ::nexttowardl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1181:11: error: '::remainderl' has not been declared
   using ::remainderl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1185:11: error: '::remquol' has not been declared
   using ::remquol;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1189:11: error: '::rintl' has not been declared
   using ::rintl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1193:11: error: '::roundl' has not been declared
   using ::roundl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1197:11: error: '::scalblnl' has not been declared
   using ::scalblnl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1201:11: error: '::scalbnl' has not been declared
   using ::scalbnl;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1205:11: error: '::tgammal' has not been declared
   using ::tgammal;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cmath:1209:11: error: '::truncl' has not been declared
   using ::truncl;
```

I haven't tried to completely delete Cygwin and re-install everything since I consider that a really bad last effort. and I really don't think editing cmath to remove all those "using"s would be a good idea since it could lead to unpredictable behavior or more compilation bugs. So ... what's wrong ?

Comment: have you installed cygwin-devel ?

Comment: Got this exact same error as well when trying to build YouCompleteMe, which tries to compile the Boost library. Also GCC 5.4.0 - installed literally 10 minutes ago. Installing cygwin-devel fixed it for me, so thanks @matzeri

Comment: @matzeri Thank you so much. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the suggestion by @matzeri: just install `cygwin-devel`

Got this exact same error as well when trying to build `YouCompleteMe`, which tries to compile the Boost library. Also GCC 5.4.0 - installed literally 10 minutes ago. Installing cygwin-devel fixed this exact error for me.

*Unfortunately, I just got a new one about `LONG_BIT definition` being wrong, but that is another question ...*